# How can I preview PDF files when clicking on a shared link?

Tags: orangedox

I am new to Orangedox. I would like to share links of PDF files. I have tested a link that I shared to myself and want to try out the download option and preview option to see the count go up in Orangedox. The download option works just fine and the download count goes up. But I cannot find a way to preview the PDF file when using the shared link, and as such the preview count does not go up. It seems it should be possible to preview the PDF since there is a preview count symbol beside the file name (whereas there is no preview count symbol beside a Word document file).

How can I preview PDF files when clicking on a shared link?

Answer (score 1):

Using the basic version of Orangedox you only get the ability to preview images, and a variety of text files.  If you would like PDF previewing & analytics, including the time spent on each page of the document you can request a [business account](https://dropbox.orangedox.com/plans/).

Feel free to contact us directly for more info